# Wrongfully declined flag?

Tags: discussion, moderators, flagging

**Incident Report:**

Two days ago I checked the mod tools and saw a flagged post appearing. The post was a common happening that a person posts an answer to a rather old question, and in the answer they simply ask a question of their own (often not directly related to the original post).

I agreed that the flag was valid and flagged it again myself. So we have a post flagged by *two* people.

Several minutes later the flag itself was declined with the reason:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Several minutes more, and another high-rep. user posted a comment directing the "answerer" to the Ask Question page, and two hours later the post was deleted by three users (I was not one of them due to timing).

---

**What *Could* Have Happened:**

Let us consider a slightly different situation for a moment, something which is not unthinkable, too.

Suppose that whoever flagged the post was a low-reputation user (or even <20k) and the flag was cleared *before* high ranking users could see it in the moderation tools. This question posted as an answer is in a *very* wrong place, and I am sure that no one who cares for the well-being of this website would want to allow such content to exist for long.

It happened that at least one of the flagging users were me (and had I not come back to see the post deleted, I would probably have raised a deletion flag myself... which could have been sitting in wait for *quite some time*). But in our hypothetical scenario none of the involved users - except the moderator who declined the flag - can delete an answer.

In such case, the answer stays in the wrong place for quite some time until someone else deletes it.

---

**Question:**

What I wonder about this is whether or not a question posted as an answer to a long-answered thread is **not** content that the moderators should be aware of.

We had an election recently, and before that such flags were never declined, I assume this is a result of new moderators not being in line with the other moderators, or raising points to other moderators about the job of a moderator.

My question is **why** was my flag declined? Is there a new description of the moderators job on this site? If there is such, can the moderators please update the common user (and the flagging users) about this description?

*(For 10k users: [the flagged post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/148835/622).)*

Comment: As you may know from many of my prior posts on meta, I believe that any decisions that can be made by the community, should be made by the community (vs. being decided by an *individual* moderator). This avoids controversial use of moderator superpowers e.g. when closing and deleting posts. This is a borderline case. But there are many other cases where posts are flagged for mod decisions that indubitably *should* be made by the community.

Comment: How **two** flagging users are not community input? Should every flag be weighed and debated on meta first? I will be happy to do so for your sake.

Comment: I *think* what Bill is saying is that if you see an answer that not only shouldn't be an answer, it shouldn't be on the page at all, then you should vote to delete it (if you can) instead of flagging it for moderator attention. But the message, "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention," (which I have also gotten recently for one of my flags) doesn't really tell the flagger anything helpful.

Comment: @Gerry: I stopped trying to think for others recently, especially Bill which I cannot read properly at all. In my experience deletion votes can stand for weeks. Flagging for a moderator attention is a way to get action taken quickly.

Comment: I think that (if they haven't done so already) the moderators should get together and agree on a policy they will all follow on these flags, and then publicize it. It would not be a good thing if the treatment of your flags were to depend on which moderator happened to be awake at the time.

Comment: @Gerry, which is why I brought this on meta. Before the election it was pretty obvious what happens: Mariano kept claiming he mostly avoids dealing with these kind of flags because he thinks it's not the job of a moderator and Zev would clear a lot of the flags with some of the work done by Willie and Qiaochu. Now we have two new moderators and it seems that the game has changed.

Comment: "Borderline case"? The "answer" is completely unrelated to the question. It was posted by a new user, possibly as a first action (certainly, nothing is in the log). It *patently* does not belong as an answer in that question, where it does not good to anybody (including the original poster)...

Comment: @Gerry Based on my (limited) experience, most users do use flags properly, invoking them only in *exceptional* cases that do *require* use of moderator superpowers. However, there are a few users who flag far too much, often in cases where the community *has* the power to make the decision, and where it would be much more *democratic* for the community to make such *subjective* decisions, rather than an individual (moderator).

Comment: @Arturo And the community has the power and wisdom to make that decision. And it did. The wisdom of the community is much greater than that of any individual.

Comment: @Bill, I know about myself and another user which are frequent flaggers. The reason I flag is for immediate of action. Had there been 100 users capable deleting answers on this sites, I would probably flag a lot less, at time of commenting there are 33 and four of those are moderators with a binding vote. **My** experience is that often deletion flags can sit and wait for quite some time. If you insist that this flag should have been "dealt with by the community" let it be dealt by the community, don't clear it. By letting it sit you de facto give it more exposure to high reputation users.

Comment: I still think, however, that until there is a very good base of 20k+ users the moderators **should** intervene. Especially in cases like the one linked, which as Arturo says, are not at all borderline.

Comment: @Bill: Sigh... Once again, I see that we live in completely different worlds. I'm doubly glad that it is not through my vote that you became a moderator. Why someone who does not believe in moderation ran for moderation is well beyond me.

Comment: @Asaf I pledged to use superpowers only when absolutely necessary, because, for one, this helps to ensure democratic decisions, and, further, helps to avoid tension. If you wish to discuss this matter in the abstract then let's do so. But I don't think it is constructive to (explicitly?) choose a borderline example  of application  such general principles. Rather, one should discuss the general criteria.

Comment: @Bill: If you say that this is a borderline example then your standards are insanely high. Should a user write something like "*F--k you a--sholes!! I HAZ QUSTEION!11*" before you claim a post is not in place and should be deleted? I have no problem starting an abstract discussion, but it is moot as long as your standard consider this as borderline where I consider it exemplary.

Comment: Once again, Bill, please avoid clearing flags if you want the community to deal with them. While the flag is not cleared other users can see it and become aware of the problem, thus flagging further (I suppose, or at least want to believe, that if that post had 16 users who flagged it, you may have considered deletion) or voting to delete if they are in that small club of users who can.

Comment: @Arturo That you disagree with another on such subjective matters does not imply that the other "does not believe in moderation". Please, if you wish to contribute, do so *constructively*.

Comment: @Asaf If you wish to pose a meta question on *general* policy on flag handling then please do so. But focusing on one specific edge case is almost never a good way to start such a general discussion.

Comment: @Bill: I will not debate the policy before we agreed on what is a borderline case. If you wish to see a borderline case go see the other flag in my profile rejected at the same time as the one mentioned. *That* flag was debatable and borderline. I insist that we first clear out the semantic disagreement before we proceed to the syntactic formulation. Note that we do mathematics this way too, first we think on the object we want as clear as possible, then we formulate abstract properties. Later we put them to the semantical test again.

Comment: @Asaf I'm happy to see that you admit that you are a "frequent flagger" and that some of your flags are borderline cases. I think it will be impossible to get any community consensus on defining precise borders on such subjective matters. But we might be able to reach a consensus on non-edge cases. So why don't you pose a general question, omitting the difficult problem of extreme cases? I think that would have much more potential of leading to constructive discussion. Generally meta discussions work best when discussing the matters in the abstract.

Comment: @Bill: There is absolutely no point in all of us agreeing that posts written in a very rude way, contain spam, offensive content, and such should be deleted. I'd think that *everyone* agree to that. I also think that the case at hand here *is* the common case, and it *is* a very good example of a post which is not offensive in any way and should be deleted. I also wish to express that I think that about 5% of my flags so far were questionable, this makes about 20 flags out of 400. Most of the flags which are unhelpful are those which invalidate other's flagging.

Comment: @Asaf: Where did you find the reason for the flag being declined? (I'm asking because I just flagged a post (at least I thought I did) and I can't find it among the flagged posts but I also don't see a reason for the flag being declined displayed anywhere.)

Comment: @joriki: The "helpful flags" link in your profile should show you a reason.

Answer (score 28):

Asaf has already said something like this in the comments, but I want to highlight it as an answer:

If a moderator does not want to intervene, then he or she shouldn't.  *Declining the flag* is not the same thing as not intervening.  It is itself an action based on a subjective decision, not made by the community.  If the flag is left to stand without action taken by a moderator, then the flag can be seen on the tools menu for users with enough points, who may then weigh in, but who are more likely to be oblivious if the flag is declined.

Comment: Generally, I do agree with that. However, there are a couple users who are raising *far* too many flags, orders of magnitude more than the norm.

Comment: @Bill: If you have a problem with me and with one or two users please be explicit about it. I already admitted for lack of mind-reading abilities. I also find it strange that *none* of the previous moderators complained, and at best there was a [directional request not to invalidate automatic flags, or to avoid "low quality" flags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4056/1543). Both of which I follow.

Comment: @Asaf As I said, *generally* I do agree with that policy. So I think, perhaps, you may be concerned about something that is nonexistent. But I do encourage you to reflect on the fact that you flag *much* more than the average user. Keep in mind the fable of the [boy who cried wolf.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Cried_Wolf)

Comment: @Bill: Most moderators have my email address, and address me when they see fit. Apparently until an hour ago **no one** said anything about the amount of flags I raised. Yes, it was discussed in one or two emails by the way. One can only wonder why you are the first one to consider my flagging excessive. It is also very weird that until two days ago I only had **seven out of nearly 500** flags declined, and about 20 which were disputed against my call. It is indeed very strange that just *now* I hear about this problem.

Comment: @Asaf So why all the fuss about 1 of your 500 flags?

Comment: There is no doubt that the other moderators agree with you, this is why all those flags were marked "helpful". I mean, if one thing gives you an incentive to stop flagging is when you are consistently being told that your flags are helpful.

Comment: @Bill: I fuss because this flag was wrongfully declined. It is a matter of principle. I stand behind my actions, and I believe that whoever declined this flag was wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't it be irrelevant how often a user flags when considering whether a particular flag is a good candidate for action/declining/ignoring?  (I mean, this would be ideal, unless there really is a problem user overwhelming the resources of the moderators with pointless flags, which is extremely far from the case here.)

Comment: @Asaf If there been not only 1, but, rather a *trend* of your 500 flags being declined for what you thought were wrong reasons, then that may have been worth discussing on meta. But that is *not* the case here. Again, please keep in mind the fable of the boy who cried wolf.

Comment: @Bill: If it was a trend of declined flags, I would have to reflect upon my flagging behavior. **Because** there is just one, which unlike the other declinations I believe is *completely* unjustified, I bring things to meta. Please, Bill, if you believe that my flaggings are cries for wolves -- by all means, I beg you to ignore them. I mean *ignore* completely, avoid them altogether and let other moderators deal with them.

Comment: @Asaf As I said, I think you are concerned about a matter that is nonexistent. I don't recall any other users raising a meta question about a *single* flag of theirs that had been declined. In your case it is roughly 1/500 flags that you raised. There is no trend and there should be no reason for such heightened concern as far as I can see.

Comment: I disagree with @Bill.  If this is a fluke matter, then fine, that could be made clear, along with a clarification of the practice of declining flags.  But rather, a moderator in this thread has *defended the particular action* that many in the community apparently disagree with.  That is not to say the moderator is right or wrong, but there is certainly a matter that exists, albeit a small matter.  (That is, I see the existent matter to be about the practice of declining flags, regardless of what percentage of a particular user's flags have been declined.)

Comment: @Jonas As I said, above, generally I agree with your answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I raised a question about a single flag of mine that had been declined - I just chose to raise it via email to team+math, rather than via meta. I believe Arturo has recently raised a similar question on meta. So I think at least three of us are experiencing moving goalposts and would like to see a clear consensus among the moderators concerning the handling of flags.

Comment: @Gerry That's fine by me. Robjohn also raised an analogous question on chat about flags that were disputed by a mod (not me), so perhaps it would be best to start a new thread about the general matter so that everyone can learn about such. Afaik, there is no official SE doc on these matters, so one has to learn on the fly. Thus it is not too surprising that there may be misassumptions and mistakes made during the learning process.

Answer (score 27):

Some quick thoughts.

1. This answer clearly doesn't belong to this question.
2. I am glad it was flagged, and if I had seen the flag I would have deleted the answer immediately.
3. It is completely normal for a few users to flag much more often than the other users, in the same way that it is completely normal for a few users to post questions or answers much more often than the other users. This is just what activity on the internet looks like.
4. It is not feasible for decisions this small to be made by the community (in the sense of a meta discussion). There are too many such decisions, and it would be a waste of time. Moderators exist so that the community can focus on more important things.

Answer (score 16):

You did the right thing bringing the matter up here, but please don't get too upset. As you say, there were two new moderators elected recently. Moderation can be a challenging task, especially for folks who *have't* spent much time using the community-moderation tools prior to being elected.

It takes time to become comfortable in the role, and everyone makes mistakes. This is one of them.

That's why there are always multiple moderators on the site - so they can assist each other in making these decisions and in learning to understand what the community expects of its moderators.

So do what you can to help them learn, either by discussing the protocols for handling different situations here (as you're doing) or by catching them in chat and talking about specific cases.

One thing I've done in the past on Stack Overflow that helped a good deal was setting up a private, scheduled chat between the old and new moderators a couple weeks post-election where the new mods could ask questions and share concerns with the more experienced ones. If the Math.SE moderators are interested, we could do that here as well.

Comment: Shog, I am not really upset. Just trying to stand my ground when a *new* moderator claims that I over-flag. I appreciate this answer very much! It also gives me a sense that my question about flagging was very much in place before the elections.

Comment: *"especially for folks who have't spent much time using the community-moderation tools prior to being elected"*  This has been and continues to be one of my biggest concerns—we seem to have a tendency to elect mods who (in pre-mod life) use voting, flagging, and other basic tools of participation in SE far less frequently than the average user.

Comment: @Shog: Perhaps add a feature that in time of candidacy the candidates can see (but not act, perhaps) the moderation tools, and perhaps add a feature which somewhat forces new moderators through some sort of bootcamp at first to familiarize themselves with the moderation tools page.

Comment: @Asaf: the former is kind of a big ask, especially considering that *most* of the tools are already available (in some form) to users with at least 10K reputation points - if someone's running for mod-ship and hasn't spent time in the 10K queue, giving them access to the mod queue probably won't accomplish much. The latter is not a bad idea at all.

Comment: @Shog: I have some more ideas about election related improvements. I think it's getting off topic here, but you can contact me by mail if you wish. (I'm sure that you can find the address... :-))

Comment: @Shog9: Perhaps the election page could prominently show a metric of how much a candidate has engaged with the 10K queue?

Comment: @Isaac: "helpful flags" are already listed, and a reasonable indicator of time spent in moderation-mode as a user; I wouldn't necessarily be opposed to edit, close, and re-open stats there as well, but the latter two are *somewhat* controversial as they're not currently public anywhere. Familiarity with the moderation tools is actually a question I like to ask in the Town Hall chats, but I wasn't able to make the one for Math.SE. Regardless, this isn't rocket science - everyone makes mistakes starting out... I trust the new moderators here will pick it up with help from y'all's feedback. ;-)

Comment: @Asaf I think the problem has more to do with lack of documentation on (diamond) moderation than anything else. Afaik there is no official SE documentation on (diamond) moderation. There are various things I had presumed about undocumented parts of the software platform that, through experience, I eventually discovered were not true. No doubt there will be more. With almost 500 flags, you probably know the flagging system better than most. I *am* listening to your feedback.